# Tweet box shows counts for web page, not post

Tags: twitter, blogs, tweets

I've installed a Tweet button per Twitter's instructions here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button.

The issue is that if you go to the homepage of my blog, http://trevormckendrick.com you'll notice that the tweet buttons show the number of times the homepage has been shared, not the post.

An example of the behavior I want can be found @ http://startupflavor.com. Notice the Tweet button counts are different on every post on the homepage.